# Remove Silverlight Animation

Tags: silverlight, animation

I have a problem with my Silverlight animation that I can't seem to fix. The problem seems to be well established, but the techniques used to solve it don't seem to work in my case.

Here is the storyboard code that I am using to animate a grid called "underGrid". underGrid is a base grid which I am applying a scale and location offset to in response to mouse input from the user, so that they can scale and move the grid in real time. The ResetGrid storyboard below simply animates from the current scale and location values back to scale {1, 1} and location {0, 0}, resetting the view for the user. I wanted to be able to apply this animation whenever the user clicks a reset button but it freezes the Scale and Translation transforms once it has run once (as discussed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx). Which means that when the user then uses the mouse to move the grid, it doesn't move. I've tried everything I can think of to stop the animation from having an affect on the dependency properties. I've tried hooking the Completed event and trying (amongst other things), stopping the animation, seeking the animation to 0, looping through the ResetGrid Children and using StoryBoard.SetTarget(). I've also tried setting the FillBehavior.. No matter what I do nothing seems to make a difference, the Scale and Translation are always tapped and cannot be set again in user-code.

Can anyone suggest anything I can try that I've not listed above (drastic or otherwise :) )? All I want is the animation to have completely stopped and detached itself on Complete.

Storyboard XAML:

```
  <Storyboard x:Name="ResetGrid">
   <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="underGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="0">
     <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
      <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
     </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
   </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="underGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="0">
     <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
      <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
     </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
   </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="underGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="1">
     <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
      <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
     </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
   </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="underGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="1">
     <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
      <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
     </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
   </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

will ResetGrid.stop() work?
I used it in my applications and the animation was cut off straight away.
 animation.stop will stop and reset, while animation.pause will just stop on where timeline it hit
if not u can put another animation of duration 0,
call this animation to place back the property

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue before too... check out this thread on Silverlight.Net which I think you might find helpful:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/68888.aspx